# Reference to parent html element in React child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A simple `Editor.jsx` component render method that renders a SVG element and a child component called `<SystemBox />`

```
render() {
 return (
  <svg id="editor">
    <SystemBox />
  </svg>
 );
}
```

In `SystemBox.jsx` I need access to the actuall SVG html element to for example get to the `getScreenCTM()` method on the SVG element.

**How do I pass a reference to the SVG element in the parent to the child component?**

I guess I could use `document.getElementById('editor')` in the `SystemBox.jsx` child component, but that doesn't right.

Comment: Yep, it's better not to use DOM APIs to manipulate DOM since they are controlled by React

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). You can create a reference to your `svg` DOM element and pass this reference by props to any custom component you've created.